# Uncaught Error: No module: MyApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework, requirejs

I load AngularJs and jQuery using RequireJs in nodeJs framework.

That is main.js

```
    require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: 'vendor/angular.min',
        bootstrap: 'vendor/twitter/bootstrap',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min',
        domReady: 'vendor/require/domReady',
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore.min'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            deps: [ 'jquery' ],
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});

require([
        'app',
        'angular-boot'
    ], function() {

});
```

in app.js

```
 define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    return angular.module('MyApp', []);
})
```

and in angular-boot.js

```
    define([ 'angular', 'domReady' ], function (angular, domReady) {
    domReady(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
    });
});
```

In my html file I have only this line, in order to declare and use requirejs. 
Not ng-ap or anything else.

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

The problem is that sometimes runs, sometimes not. 
The error when it doesn't run is

> Uncaught Error: No module: MyApp

If there is any thought about it, I would really appreciate it. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your shim, you need to setup the `app` as a dependency to `angular-boot`. Your `angular-boot` file depends on `app` (where `MyApp` is defined), and because the load order for these two files is not specified, sometimes `angular-boot` loads before the `app` and thus produces that error.

To remedy, just update your shim as such:

```
shim: {
  angular: {
    deps: [ 'jquery' ],
    exports: 'angular'
  },
  'angular-boot': {
    deps: ['app']
  }
}
```

and than, since you don't need to include the 'app' explicitly your `require` call can be reduced to:

```
require(['angular-boot']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help me. What other options you can try?

Comment: @martinixs If this answer doesn't help you than that means you have a different problem. You might want to create a separate question, referencing this one.

Comment: Important to note that you must use a shim and not simply add "app" as a requirejs dependency.  Shims specify load order (or at least allow you more control) than require functions.