# Angular.js: Uncaught error, no module: myapp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying too bootstrap an angular.js project. This is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="{% url 'app' %}" />

    <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view>
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var url = function(path) { return '{{ STATIC_URL }}' + path };
    </script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/project/app.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/project/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `url 'app'` on the head simply prints the subpath, /app, for example. This is my app.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($router) {
    $router.when('/', {
        templateUrl: url('partials/foo.html'),
        controller: controllers.Foo
    });
}]);
```

The problem is that everytime I try to run it, an exception is raised: `Uncaught Error: No module: myapp`, and this is almost the same way [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) works. I searched on Google and StackOverflow but none of the answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585085/uncaught-error-no-module-myapp) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531197/how-to-run-angularjs-example)) helped me.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvfnN/) about my error (you should open the browser's console to see it). What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle which reproduces the issue ?

Comment: @Blackhole, it's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvfnN/). I tried my best to put it on jsFiddle (open your console to see the issue).

Comment: I think your STATIC_URL variable isn't defined. It's outside of a angular scope, so you cannot use {{}}.  Try using a constant string for your src instead of an angular variable.

Comment: @flim, just to clarify, STATIC_URL is a django variable, and it's rendered on server side.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The order of your script is very important, try putting it in your `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.variable = "Hello";
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <p>{{variable}}</p>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vvfnN/2/

Answer (score 10):

Complementing [AlexCheuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17283756/1390427)'s answer, I realized that my app.js file was involved in a closure:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    // all angular.js stuff
)(jQuery);
```

Removing the closure it worked (without changing the orders as Alex said)! I don't know exacly why, but that's ok.

Comment: @lsmagalhaes, the reason that removing the jQuery's ready call fixed your problem is that Angular will bootstrap on the DOMContentLoaded event, which happens to be the same event that jQuery calls its ready handler.  

What's happening is that Angular will bootstrap and look for your module based on the value of ng-app, but since the jQuery ready handler has not run yet, the module will not have been created yet. That's why you were getting the `Uncaught Error: No module: myapp` error.

Comment: This actually seems to be the answer. on jsFiddle, just load angularjs on "no-wrap -in head" or "no-wrap -in body" and the error is gone. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem but none of the above trick worked for me but this one, see the setting in image

Change from "OnLoad" to "No wrap - "

[image]

Comment: very good answer.. this is worked for me,,thankss.... can u explain what is the meaning of No wrap-in <head>

Answer (score 0):

In my case when using IIFE notation I forgot self invoke parentheses.

```
(function () {
     angular.module("adminApp", []); 
}() //don't forget self invoke parentheses
);
```

Comment: *forgot please, RIP english

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same error but i was doing a silly mistake, i was not including the controller.js file in my jsp page.
just included this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/controller.js"></script>
```

and it worked excellently.

Answer (score -4):

I ran into a similar issue where there, while running Yeoman/grunt server.
What fixed it for me, was restarting the grunt server.

Comment: This has nothing to do with this issue.