# Testing with Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm a beginner with Karma, and I can't make a test work on my project.
I tried with this :
http://blog.codeship.com/mocha-js-chai-sinon-frontend-javascript-code-testing-tutorial/
The exemple works with the "html page testing", but I can't make it work with *start karma.conf.js* (I got : Executed 0 of 0 ERROR)

Here is my karma.conf.js file :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
    files: [
        'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'src/client/api/category/category.model.js'
        **'test.js'** (edit)

    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
    });
  };
```

Here is the file I want to test : (src/client/api/category/category.model.js)

```
angular.module("aq.kiosk.api.category.models", [])
.factory("CategoryModel", [
    function () {

        var CategoryModel = function (data) {

            this.id = "";
            this.name = "";
            this.description = "";
            this.mediaUrls = [];
            this.kind = "";
            this.childCount = "";
            this.issueCount = "";
            this.issues = [];

            if (angular.isDefined(data)) {
                this.parse(data);
            }
        };

        CategoryModel.prototype.parse = function (data) {
            if (data) {
                var self = this;
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    self[key] = value;
                });
            }
        };

        return CategoryModel;
    }
]);
```

And here is my test file :

```
describe("categorymodel", function() {

var data = {
            childCount: "0",
            description: "",
            id: "16",
            issueCount: 0,
            kind: "",
            mediaUrls: [],
            name: "Lorem Ipsum"
        };

beforeEach(module('aq.kiosk.api.category.models'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_CategoryModel_) {
CategoryModel = _CategoryModel_;
```

}));

```
  describe("constructor", function(){
    it('assigns a name', function () {
      expect(CategoryModel(data)).to.have.property('name', "Lorem Ipsum");
    });

  });

});
```

**EDIT :
Thank you very much, now it works **

Comment: Where's the code that creates the module? `angular.module("aq.kiosk.api.category.models")` assumes it is already created. If you're trying to create the module in your *category.model.js* file then the syntax would be `angular.module("aq.kiosk.api.category.models", [])`. If the module is created by another file, how is that file included?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js: Uncaught error, no module: myapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283291/angular-js-uncaught-error-no-module-myapp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing referencing your test spec

You have

```
files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'src/client/api/category/category.model.js'
],
```

It should be

```
files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'src/client/api/category/category.model.js',
    'specs/category.spec.js'
],
```

Also  you will need to (per ivarni's comment) change your syntax

from

```
angular.module("aq.kiosk.api.category.models")
```

to

```
angular.module("aq.kiosk.api.category.models", [])
```

for your beforeEach to work

```
beforeEach(module('aq.kiosk.api.category.models'));
```

Comment: That would give the same error as it blows up already in `category.model.js` but good catch, they're both issues that must be fixed.

Comment: Ah well, I'll leave this up for a while - one of the many answers to this question :)

Comment: Ok thank you, I added the test file, and the file where the module is created. And now I have this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: CategoryModel is not defined (in the test file). The "beforeEach(module('aq.kiosk.api.category.models'));" is supposed to include it, no ?

Comment: I corrected it adding an other file (category.module.js) where the "angular.module("aq.kiosk.api.category.models", [])" is done (in my updated question), and I also tried to write it directly as ivarni suggested, but I still have the same error

Comment: If I understand your correctly, you did not need to add a new module file but instead need to edit category.model.js to include the [] in your module definition.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but still the same error : "CategoryModel is not defined"

Comment: it is the "var category = new CategoryModel(data);" in the test file

Comment: I added something (see my updated question) in my test, and it works ! Thank you very much :)